# Python masked arrays producing NaNs with np.array

Tags: python, nan, masked-array

I am trying to select a subset of a larger grid to perform a finite element analysis to iterate over between two arrays; a masked array and an unmasked array but i have come across a problem of NaNs appearing from the mask when using np.arrays. I originally used masks here to try to **avoid**  NaN issues including NaN == NaN (False) etc... but the mask itself seems to be creating NaNs when used with np.arrays!

> **coordinate arrays to iterate over:**

```
array = np.array(list(np.arange(5))*5).reshape(5,5)
big_array =  np.array([array,array,array])
```

> **apply masks on the coordinate arrays:**

```
mask1 = np.ma.masked_array(big_array, mask = (big_array>2))
mask2 = np.ma.masked_array(big_array, mask = (big_array>3))
```

> **iterate over the coordinate arrays for the masked vs. unmasked comparison:**

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
            array_group = np.array([ big_array[0,i,j], big_array[1,i,j] ]) 
            array_group2 = np.array([ mask1[0,i,j], mask2[1,i,j] ]) 
            print array_group
```

> **^^no NaNs from array_group but.. ^^^**

```
        print array_group2
```

> **NaNs appear for the masked array_group2 here**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, your `mask1` outputs :

```
[[[0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]]

 [[0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]]

 [[0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]
  [0 1 2 -- --]]]
```

The little dashes are the masked data that causes the `nan` values to appear.
As to how to fix this... I believe  it depends on how you want to treat these datas : replace these dashes by 0, False, delete them... whatever.

Comment: Yes the dashes are the mask where the nans appear, but why cant the mask handle the np.array iteration? I cant replace with zeros or integers as that data will be interpreted as the 0,0 coordinate throughout. i cant delete the entries as the array shape needs to be the same between the grids. I was hoping the mask would simply maintain itself through a basic iteration

Comment: As I was saying : What you want to do if you encounter a masked value is up to you. You didn't say anything about that, and/or how to get there.